# How to add inline spacing in pdfPCell

Tags: itext

I need to add Space between two lines in iTextSharp pdfPCell

```
Chunk chunk = new Chunk("Received  Rs(In Words) :    " + " " + myDataTable.Tables[1].Rows[0]["Recieved"].ToString(), font8);
PdfPTable PdfPTable = new PdfPTable(1);                    
PdfPCell PdfPCell =new PdfPCell(new Phrase(Chunk ));
PdfPCell .Border = PdfCell.NO_BORDER;
PdfPTable .AddCell(PdfPCell );
```

Comment: Space between two lines in the context of PDF is called *leading*, There have been a lot of questions and answers about setting the leading in cells (also search for *text mode* versus *composite mode*). However, when I look at your code snippet, I only see one line. Is it possible that you don't want to add space between two lines, but between two chunks that are *on the same line*? Please clarify, otherwise you risk getting an answer about leading, which may not be what you need.

Comment: Thanks for your Replay,  But some time it will have more than one line

Comment: As explained in the comment to my answer, I've made three guesses trying to figure out wha is meant with "inline space": (1) space separating two parts of text on the same line, one to the left, the other to the right, (2) space between the lines (the *leading* that separates consecutive line), (3) non-breaking space (`&nbsp;`) inside the line. According to the OP none of these guesses were correct. This question either needs clarification, or it needs to be closed as "unclear what is asked".

Comment: You never gave any feedback informing me if my answer solved your problem.

Answer (score 3):

Please take a look at the following screen shot:

[image]

Based on your code snippet, I assume that you want to separate `"Received Rs (in Words):"` from `"Priceless"`, but it's not clear to me what you want to happen if there is more than one line, so I have written 3 examples:

**Example 1:**

```
table = new PdfPTable(2);
table.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_LEFT);
table.setWidthPercentage(60);
table.setSpacingAfter(20);
cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Received Rs (in Words):"));
cell.setBorder(PdfPCell.LEFT | PdfPCell.TOP | PdfPCell.BOTTOM);
table.addCell(cell);
cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Priceless"));
cell.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_RIGHT);
cell.setBorder(PdfPCell.RIGHT | PdfPCell.TOP | PdfPCell.BOTTOM);
table.addCell(cell);
document.add(table);
```

In this example, I put `"Received Rs (in Words):"` and `"Priceless"` in two different cells, and I align the content of the first cell to the left and the content of the second cell to the right. This creates space between the two `Chunk`s.

**Example 2**

```
// same code as above, except for:
table.setWidthPercentage(50);
```

I decreased the width of the table to show you what happens if some content doesn't fit a cell. As we didn't define any widths for the columns, the two columns will have an equal width, but as `"Received Rs (in Words):"` needs more space than `"Priceless"`, the text doesn't fit the width of the cell and it is wrapped. We could avoid this, by defining a larger with for the first column when compared to the second column.

**Example 3:**

```
table = new PdfPTable(1);
table.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_LEFT);
table.setWidthPercentage(50);
Phrase p = new Phrase();
p.add(new Chunk("Received Rs (In Words):"));
p.add(new Chunk(new VerticalPositionMark()));
p.add(new Chunk("Priceless"));
table.addCell(p);
document.add(table);
```

This example is very close to what you have, but instead of introducing space characters to create space, I introduce a special chunk: `new VerticalPositionMark())`. This chunk will separate the two parts of the `Phrase` by introducing as much space as possible.

**If this doesn't answer your question,** you were probably looking for the concept known as *leading*. Leading is the space between the baseline of two lines of text. If that is the case, please read the following Q&As:

- [Changing text line spacing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21810133/changing-text-line-spacing)
- [Spacing/Leading PdfPCell's elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20145742/spacing-leading-pdfpcells-elements)
- [Paragraph leading inside table cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25850566/paragraph-leading-inside-table-cell)
- [Adding more text to a cell in table in itext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25325408/adding-more-text-to-a-cell-in-table-in-itext)
- [How to maintain indentation if a paragraph takes new line in PdfPCell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28073190/itext-maintain-identing-if-paragraph-takes-new-line-in-pdfpcell)

**If your question isn't about leading,** then maybe you're just looking for the concept known as *non-breaking space*:

- [How to use non breaking space in iTextSharp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8132211/how-to-use-non-breaking-space-in-itextsharp)
- [Generating pdf file using Itext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8381520/generating-pdf-file-using-itext)

Comment: Thank you for your Answer, BY this code we can add space between two tables or two columns. But i need to add inline space in a cell

Comment: @S.P Please define "inline space". My guesses were: (1) space separating two parts of text, one to the left, the other to the right, (2) space between the lines (*leading*), (3) non-breaking space inside the line. Apparently, I guess wrong 3 times, so if you want me to help you, you will have to clarify. I don't think I'm the only person who thinks this question isn't clear.

Comment: Inline space means, The space between two lines in a cell or in a paragraph